# Can you hibernate (save RAM to disk) a docker container when you stop all containers or docker exits (using docker-compose, not regular docker)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container which has ssh-keys added to it (i.e. running [nardeas/ssh-agent](https://github.com/nardeas/ssh-agent)). I want to keep this container alive indefinitely because the `ssh-add` gets reset when the container stops. Is there any way I can hibernate this container when exiting docker or turning off my computer?

What I need is a docker-compose configuration that lets me save the ram to disk when stopping the container, so that when it comes back up it still has the same ssh-keys added and I don't need to add it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Docker's `checkpoint` command:

> Checkpoint and Restore is an experimental feature that allows you to freeze a running container by checkpointing it, which turns its state into a collection of files on disk. Later, the container can be restored from the point it was frozen.

```
$ docker checkpoint create CONTAINER_NAME CHECKPOINT_ID
```

To restore a container:

```
$ docker start --checkpoint CHECKPOINT_ID CONTAINER_NAME
```

See: [Docker Reference - Checkpoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint/)

In regards to setting something similar up using `docker compose`, Please see [`docker compose events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.42/#tag/System/operation/SystemEvents) in which it was proposed to set some form of system "hooks" within compose. (see: [Proposal: docker-compose events #1510](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1510))

Comment: Can this be used in docker-compose?

Comment: @Damian docker compose events might be of interest in which you can react to shutdown events: [Docker - Reference - Monitor Events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.42/#tag/System/operation/SystemEvents) Also see: [Docker - Documentation - events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) - I have updated the answer to reflect your updated title, hope it helps.